# Get every combination of bits for two binary numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm

For two numbers, lets say 5 (101) and 3 (011), what is the most efficient way to get every number that is a combination of the different bits in these two numbers. (i.e the solution would be 101, 011, 001, 111). The number of these is just 2^(# of bits different) which I can get from an XOR, and counting the set bits. I'm trying to do this in C++.

I tried to do an XOR and go from there, but that only tells me which bits are different, and also I don't know how to loop through the bits to record down every combination.

Comment: [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) is very handy for working with bits.

Comment: Break it down into phases. First step, figure out which bits are set. That's just an or operation, not xor.

Comment: Just work out which positions (bit numbers) are set in both values.   The generate all values that can be produced by toggling one or more of those bits on and off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most concise way I can think of is this:

```cpp
void find_bit_combinations(unsigned a, unsigned b) {
    for (unsigned mask = 1; mask != 0; mask <<= 1) {
        if ((a & mask) != (b & mask)) {
            find_bit_combinations(a & ~mask, b & ~mask);
            find_bit_combinations(a | mask, b | mask);
            return;
        }
    }
    std::cout << a << '\n';
}
```

The basic idea is that we go through all the bits from least to most significant, until there is a mismatch.
If so, we recurse, where `a` and `b` both have the same bit set or unset.
The base case is that `a` and `b` are the same, which means we have found one result.

```cpp
int main() {
    find_bit_combinations(0b011, 0b101);
}
```

This code prints `1`, `5`, `3`, and `7`. Instead of `std::cout <<`, you can obviously also add the results to some container.

### Further optimizations

The current code is very simple and concise, but far from optimal.
Here are some ways to improve it:

1. check initially if `a == b` and don't loop if so
2. don't start at the least significant bit, but the lowest set bit in `a ^ b`

   - `std::countr_zero` is helpful
3. don't stop at the most significant bit, but at the greatest set bit in `a ^ b`

   - `std::countl_zero` is helpful

### Generalization to N numbers

You can easily generalize this to more than two numbers.
The condition in the if statement is generally checking whether *all* numbers are equal.
For three numbers, this is `(a & mask) != (b & mask) || (a & mask) != (c & mask)`.
For a range of numbers, this is:

```cpp
std::ranges::adjacent_find(numbers
  | std::views::transform([&](unsigned x) { return x & mask; }),
std::ranges::not_equal_to)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Hardware-accelerated approach using PDEP

As an alternative to my first answer (which is more portable), there is an x86_64 variant which relies heavily on the [PDEP (Parallel Bit Deposit)](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pdep) instruction.

The basic idea is that use a dense counter from 0 to 2<sup>n</sup> where n is the number of differing bits.
PDEP is then used to distribute the dense counter bits into the right places. Here are some examples to illustrate this:

```cpp
// left operand is source, right operand is mask
_pdep_u32(0b00, 0b1001) = 0b0000
_pdep_u32(0b01, 0b1001) = 0b0001
_pdep_u32(0b10, 0b1001) = 0b1000
_pdep_u32(0b11, 0b1001) = 0b1001
```

The implementation looks as follows:

```cpp
#include <x86intrin.h>
#include <cstdint>
#include <bit>
#include <cstdio>

void consume(std::uint32_t x) {
    std::printf("%u", x);
}

void find_bit_combinations_32(std::uint32_t a, std::uint32_t b) {
    std::uint32_t mask = a ^ b;
    std::uint32_t common_ones = a & b;
    std::uint32_t counter_limit = _pext_u32(std::uint32_t(-1), mask);
    std::size_t i = 0;
    do {
        consume(_pdep_u32(i, mask) | common_ones);
    } while (i++ != counter_limit);
}

int main() {
    find_bit_combinations_32(3, 5);
}
```

See https://godbolt.org/z/164YnxeY4

This prints `1357`.

### Generalization to N numbers

You can generalize this to more than two numbers by computing the N-input OR for XOR results and N-input AND for `mask` and `common_ones` respectively.
This changes the computation to:

```cpp
std::uint32_t mask = (a ^ b) | (a ^ c) | (a ^ d) | /* ... */;
std::uint32_t common_ones = a & b & c & d & /* ... */;
```